# div / span (a) border bottom: different sized gap

Tags: html, css

I've got a class named *underlined*:

```
<style>
.underlined {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted blue;
}
</style>
```

But comparing a `span` and a `div` of this class, the gap between the text and the stroke is different sized:

```
<span class="underlined">underlined text</span><br>
<br>
<div class="underlined">underlined text</div>
```

I tried to add some lines to *underlined* (I want it to stay in the [baseline grid](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grundlinienraster)):

```
<style>
.underlined {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted blue;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  outline: 0px;
  outline-offset: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 21px;  /* which is the whole body's line height*/
}
</style>
```

It is still in the baseline grid now, but also the gap is still not the same. :(

Has anybody a idea?

Thank you very much!

Comment: look i found out it has to do with the font size:https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FUEG6OPDAIYR but i still dont't get it.

Comment: @g014m, Try my answer below. It may works for you.
https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/aLurpoxy/6/

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might occur because `div` tags by default have `display: block` whereas `span` tags have `display: inline`. In order to avoid that simply add `display: block` or any other value you might need to your `.underlined` class.

```css
.underlined {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted blue;
}

span.underlined {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span class="underlined">underlined text</span><br>
<br>
<div class="underlined">underlined text</div>
```

Comment: thanks but i want the span to be only content-width and the div 100%. now its both 100%

Comment: look i found out it has to do with the font size: w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FUEG6OPDAIYR   but i still dont't get it.

Comment: To do that set the span to `display: inline-block` and leave div's default display.

Comment: I've edited the answer to show what I meant (span with `.underlined` class), but you can always use another class.

Answer (score 0):

`span` tag is an inline element, which means you cannot set height to it,

In order to make it work add `display:inline-block` or  `display:block` to `underline` class

```css
.underlined {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted blue;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  outline: 0px;
  outline-offset: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 21px;  /* which is the whole body's line height*/
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span class="underlined">underlined text</span><br>
<br>
<div class="underlined">underlined text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to apply `display:inline-block;` for both elements.Then line height issue will be solved.

```css
.underlined {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted blue;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  outline: 0px;
  outline-offset: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 21px;  /* which is the whole body's line height*/
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#ccc;
}

div.underlined {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<span class="underlined">underlined text</span><br>
<br>
<div class="underlined">underlined text</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/aLurpoxy/6/

This works for you.Try this and let me know if there is any problem.
Thanks.

Comment: thank you. now gap is the same! but both the div's and span's gap is now bigger than as a original span (which is very important to keep the overall baseline grid): jsfiddle.net/czmobgf9/6

Comment: cool the gap is gorgeous, but if its a div "underlined"s  border-bottom shall be 100% too (not only the invisible parent box).  sorry im not native speaker dont know how to explain it well

Comment: @g014m, https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/czmobgf9/19/
Is this what you explain? Check and let me know.